# I'm sorry to be so vague, but does anyone know why this doesn't work?

Tags: python, python-3.x

sorry, does anyone know why this program doesn't work? I'm very new to python (as you can see from my inefficient programming), and I can't think of any reason why this souldn't work. Please help. Thankyou!

```
#Land Game Calculator

game = 1

hamlet = 0
village = 0
town = 0
city = 0
capital = 0
palace = 0
farm = 0
factory = 0
ruins = 0
apolw = 0
apoll = 0
polw = 0
poll = 0

squaresused = hamlet+village+town+city+capital+palace+farm+factory+ruins+apolw+apoll+polw+poll

income = hamlet+(village*2)+(town*3)+(city*4)+(capital*5)+(palace*6)+farm+(factory*3)


while game == 1:
    if input("What would you like to do? ") == hamlet:
        hamlet = hamlet+(int(input("How many would you like to add? ")))
        print("There are now "+str(hamlet)+" of them")

    elif input("What would you like to do? ") == village:
        village = village+(int(input("How many would you like to add? ")))
        print("There are now "+str(village)+" of them")

    elif input("What would you like to do? ") == town:
        town = town+(int(input("How many would you like to add? ")))
        print("There are now "+str(village)+" of them")
```

Comment: You _need_ to describe what you expect this program to do. But shouldn't that last line be `print("There are now "+str(town)+" of them")`? Also, what's the purpose of the `squaresused` and `income` calculations before the `while` loop that you never use?

Comment: What do you want the program to do ?

Comment: You are in an infinite loop. Also your variables have integers in them and you are getting strings as input and you are trying to compare these two before converting the input to integers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you're comparing strings with integers.
This lies in the `input` lines:

```
if input("What would you like to do? ") == hamlet:
```

Here, `hamlet` is an `int`, defined as `hamlet = 0`.
On the other hand, `input()` returns a `str`.
The value returned by `input` will never be equal to `hamlet`.

What you mean to do is, I presume, trigger a different action according to what the user typed in.
I guess you expect the user to type either `"hamlet"`, `"village"`, or `"town"`.
Therefore, the comparison should be on those strings rather on the variables:

```
if input("What would you like to do? ") == "hamlet":
```

Comment: I tried putting quotation marks around hamlet but it makes the problem even worse

Comment: @Gurneyguy I'd rather say, it lets the other problems appear :) If you still have problems, don't hesitate to ask new questions. However, as you can see, this question was not really well received. This is because it it -as you noticed- too vague. If you expect answers, you should make your question as clear as possible, especially regarding the goal of your code, and the behaviour you're getting vs the one you're expecting.

Comment: Perhaps also read the [help] guidance for creating a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

The while loop wasn't working properly, but it's fixed by changing from calling an `if input...` within each paragraph

```
command = ""
game = 1
while game == 1:
    game = 1
    command = input("What would you like to do? ")
    if command == hamlet:
        hamlet = hamlet+(int(input("How many would you like to add? ")))
        print("There are now "+str(hamlet)+" of them")
        game = 1

    elif command == village:
        game = 1
        village = village+(int(input("How many would you like to add? ")))
        print("There are now "+str(village)+" of them")
        game = 1
```